# osm2pgsql: database "gis" does not exist

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, mapbox, osm2pgsql

I am currently attempting to use [OSM Bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) to quickly style some OSM data, so I can export tiles without spending hours writing Carto in TileMill.

This is my first time using ***osm2pgsql*** to import OSM (**.pbf**) data into PostgreSQL. It seems that I am running from one issue into the next (missing *style* file, no *hstore*, etc. ) and I have just hit a point where I am not sure how to progress anymore.

The following message keeps popping up:

```
Error: Connection to database failed: FATAL:  database "gis" does not exist
```

I have nowhere entered that I want to access a database called *gis* .

Executing the help command and looking at the docs I realize that:

```
 -d|--database The name of the PostgreSQL database to connect to (default: gis).
```

Which tells me that it is most likely looking for the *default database*, which I do not understand, as I have indicated to use my already-created database (*ethiopia*):

[image]

Here is the command I have entered:

```
F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia>osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres -S -hstore F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style  -U postgres -d ethiopia ethiopia-latest.osm.pbf
```

If it is easier for you to look at a cmd screenshot, here it is:

[image]

The command that is featured on the [OSM Bright page](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright#using-osm2pgsql) is definitely not sufficient in my case.

**EDIT SOLUTION**:

Because the solution is all hidden in comments, I will mention here what solved my issue:
1) Create a database and add the hstore to it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore
```

2) make sure to set the password, not in the osm2pgsql statement, but before, like:

```
SET pgpassword=postgres
```

3) start osm2pgsql

4) Execute the following command:

```
 osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres --hstore -S F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style -d ethiopia F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\et hiopia-latest.osm.pbf
```

Comment: Think you need to have a database called 'gis' like here http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/setting-up-postgresql/

Comment: I have been using that tutorial (until a certain point), but my general understanding is that the database does not have to be named *gis*. Also, where on that page do you see that? Maybe I missed it, but it looks like their database is called *gisdb*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with the style file option. Try:

```
F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia>osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres --hstore -S F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style  -U postgres -d ethiopia ethiopia-latest.osm.pbf
```

If the user needs to give a password, you might have to put it on the command line as well.

It might help to always give the full path to the pbf file.

Comment: My database does use a password. Where and how would I have to insert that? I have tried the *-W* command before, but it was not accepted.

Comment: OK, so full path even though I cd'ed to the place where the .pbf is located?

Comment: This would be my updated statement, with the full path to the OSM data: 

osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres -hstore -S F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style -U postgres -d ethiopia F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\et
hiopia-latest.osm.pbf

Comment: PS: I now keep getting *osm2pgsql: illegal option -- t*. I have no idea where this would be coming from.

Comment: what version of postgres/postgis are you using? new versions require SET pgpassword=postgres http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510428/osm2pgsql-windows-illegal-option-w-error

Comment: My commandline uses `--hstore`. I don't know if it makes a difference. I disabled passwords.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help! I got it to work by first entering the password, thenstarting osm2pqsql and then executing the following: osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres --hstore -S F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style -d ethiopia F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\et hiopia-latest.osm.pbf

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Editor create db 'gis'

```
-- Database: gis

-- DROP DATABASE gis;

CREATE DATABASE gis
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

[image]

Comment: I have just created this new database, and executed the following command:

osm2pgsql -c -G -U postgres -S F:\randomGISstuff\ethi
opia\default.style -d gis ethiopia-latest.osm.pbf

However, I am now again getting the hstore error message (which I have created after creating the DB). Where do I have to add the *-hstore* command?

Comment: You forgot to add hstore extension. Run the  querry 'Create extension hstrore;' to add it to your dbase.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is messed up. Breaking it down,

- You are specifying `-U postgres` twice. Although it shouldn't cause any errors, there's no reason to do it twice. Importing with the `postgres` user is also bad practice.
- `-S -hstore F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style` sets the style to be "`-hstore`, which isn't what you want unless you have a file named `-hstore` which contains your style. It then tells it to load the OSM data in `F:\randomGISstuff\ethiopia\default.style`, which is where the actual style probably is, not the data.

  Alternately, it might tell osm2pgsql to use the options `-h`, `-s`, `-t`, `-o`, `-r`, and `-e`.

If you fix your command line, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. In my case, it seems to be an issue with older versions of `osm2pgsql`.

With an older version `osm2pgsql SVN version 0.88.1 (64bit id space)`, I had to specify `-d mydatabase` explicitly even if it is a default database in PostgreSQL which works with `psql`. Otherwise, `osm2pgsql` assumes its own default database and reports the error about database "gis" does not exist.

In a newer version `osm2pgsql version 0.96.0 (64 bit id space)`, `osm2pgsql` works fine for the default database without needing `-d`.